# Adding JAXA weather map tiles in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, weather, jaxa

Is there any way I can add [JAXA rainfall layer](https://sharaku.eorc.jaxa.jp/GSMaP/) as a Leaflet layer. If not what other options are available for rainfall/ppt layer other than OpenWeather map?